# SQL Sum Elements of a third table based upon an ID in two others

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have three SQL tables that contain what I'll call projects, project items, and hours added to project items. After a simple join statement I have the following:

```
Project.id     Item_num
1              1
1              2
1              3
2              1
etc
```

with a query such as

```
SELECT dbo.Project.id
, dbo.Item.item_num
FROM dbo.Project
JOIN dbo.Item
ON Project.id = Item.id
```

Please note there is a corresponding id between the project table and the item table. I need to now add the sum of hours that are in a third table to the right of the item_num column. The third table looks like the following (I'll call it Hours):

```
Employee name     Project.id     Item_num         Hours
ID 1              1              1                2
ID 2              1              1                1
```

and the result I want to get is:

```
Project.id     Item_num          Hours Total
1              1                 3
etc
```

I know that I need something in pseudo code that looks like: 
SUM(Hours) AS Total Hours
IF dbo.Project.id = dbo.Hours.Project.id AND dbo.Item.Item_num = dbo.Hours.Item_num
What would be the best way to implement this in a query? Thanks in advance for any help to a SQL nooby.

Comment: Hello Bird welcome to StackOverflow, next time try to provide a 
[**SqlFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/5368b/6) so we can understand the problem better and give you an answer 
much faster – Also please read [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) 
And [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The problem I see here is the db schema isn't clear. A better description will save lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this.

I'm sure on your sample some of the column name are wrong.
For example `Hour` field `Project.ID` I rename to `ProjectID`

```
SELECT P.id, I.item_num, SUM(H.Hours)
FROM dbo.Project P
INNER JOIN dbo.Item I
    ON P.id = I.id
INNER JOIN dbo.Hours H
    ON H.Item_num = I.Item_num
   AND H.ProjectID = P.ID
GROUP BY P.id, I.item_num
```

Comment: Thank you for the responses. They helped me make sure I was going in the right direction and were almost 100% what I needed. The only small change I had to make for in my particular implementation was a LEFT OUTER JOIN in the second join statement because not all items had hours. Other than that worked perfect. Thx!

Comment: Glad I help,  Please consider accept my answer and upvote when you have the privilege.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dbo.Project.id
     , dbo.Item.item_num
     , sum(Hours) as Hours
FROM dbo.Project
JOIN dbo.Item
ON   Project.id = Item.id
JOIN dbo.Hours
ON   Project.id = Hours.projectid  -- <-- your name here
GROUP BY dbo.Project.id
       , dbo.Item.item_num
```

That's what I think you want.

The rule with any aggregate like SUM() is that GROUP BY repeats any non-aggregate names.  Here you want hours by project & item.

Comment: Hello James. I don't understand the code comment `your name here` maybe a typo? Also I think query need include `projectID` in second join or all item in one project will add to the others projects.